# Sum quantities in tree structure

Tags: neo4j

I have a tree structure containing quantities in property of each node.
I want to build up the sums like adding the quantities of child nodes and then multiply the sum with the quantity of the parent. This calculated quantity will then be used in the next parent when he collects the child quantities.

I can not modify a property within the node because the structure is used for calculating quantities in different sections of the tree.

I attached virtual nodes to the existing tree containing copies of the quantities. The problem is: I cannot execute matches on the virtual nodes and their relations. Is there a way to use a mixture of "real" nodes and virtual nodes as a database to execute cypher queries on them?

I am open to alternative solutions...

Thanks

Comment: use multiple properties on node, one for quantities and other for you calculations

Comment: As I mentioned before I cannot use properties in the nodes, because each node can be linked to thousands of leaves and users can inspect different parts of the tree, so each one has to get its own result sets that will have different quantities in the same nodes. That's why I tried to use virtual nodes.

Comment: Instead of virtual nodes, you could use special "real" nodes (say, with special labels) to store the temporary data for each subtree of interest. Once you are done with a subtree's calculation, delete the corresponding special nodes.

Comment: Yes, I would have to use unique nodes for each query process (identified by a uuid) and they have to be cleaned up afterwards as you say. (I then would use unique properties for the query instead). I cannot believe that virtual nodes are not accessible in a query. I thought after using the with statement that returns a mixture of real nodes and relations combined with virtual ones I could start new matches to do further modifications and filtering, but that is not the case. So it seems that the only use for virtual nodes seems to be the visualisation in the browser or bloom...